# Google Colaboratory上で.pyファイルを編集したい

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

タイトルの通りGoogleColaboratory上で.pyファイルを編集したいです。

具体的に言うとpipでインストールした.pyファイルを編集したいです。
編集できないでしょうか。

或いは自分でアップロードした物をimport出来ないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

対象ファイルをダウンロードし、ローカル環境にて編集した後にサイドアップロードするとよいのではないでしょうか。

少し具体的に書くと Colaboratory 上でインストールしたパッケージを

```
!pip show <package-name>
```

にてインストール先を確認し、対象ファイルのPATHを調べた後に

```
from google.colab import files
files.download(<対象ファイルのPATH>)
```

を行いローカル環境に一度ダウンロードをして編集を行います
その後、

```
files.upload()
```

にて編集後のファイルをカレントディレクトリにアップロードし、

```
!cp <対象ファイル> <対象ファイルのPATH>
```

として上書きをすることができます。
編集したファイルを使いまわしたい場合は、ファイルをGoogle Drive上に置いておき、Colaboratory 上にマウントしてコピーするとよいかと思います。

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

!cp "/content/drive/My Drive/対象ファイル"  <対象ファイルのPATH>
```

---

自作のパッケージを使う場合はもっと簡単で、単にカレントディレクトリにアップロード（またはGoogle Driveからのコピー）を行い、import するだけとなります。